# Why am I getting a panic with Perl 5.10, Mason, and Apache?

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl, mason, panic

I'm developing an application using Perl 5.10, [HTML::Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/), and apache 2.2. This is the first time I've used Perl 5.10 for a big project. I get a strange behavior every once in a while. The application dies with a very strange  error:

```
panic: attempt to copy value
to a freed scalar b87acf34 at ...
```

I guess my question is it Perl 5.10 because I've never experienced this before, or is it some other faulty dependency?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this has anything to do with your error (probably not), but mod_perl+mason+perl5.10 is a no go. Perl 5.10 introduced at least one big bug that leads to segmentation faults under some conditions: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=480480#24

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm a messy person I've should have researched it before. Probably I'll have to downgrade my Perl distribution to 5.8.8.
Cheers.

Comment: Yep perl 5.10 is to blame I downgraded to perl 5.8.8 and I stopped getting errors. Sweet